# Trouble with opening files in python

Tags: file-upload, python-3.x

I was trying to write a program where I can upload a file that has first and last names in it and create a new file with the first letter of each first name followed by the last name.

The file that I created is a textfile and the lines would be like this:

```
firstname1 lastname1 (for example, john smith)
firstname2 lastname2 (for example jane jones)
firstname 3 lastname3 (for example jane doe)
etc...
```

I want to create a file that would look like this:

```
jsmith
jjones
jdoe
```

The issue that I am getting is that when I open the file in python it gives me all of these weird unwanted characters before getting to the actual text of the file. The book I am using to learn from doesn't say anything about this which is why i am posting here.

For example when I upload the file and run the following command:

```
newfile=open("example.file.rtf","r")
for i in newfile:
  print(i)
```

I get this:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf949\cocoasubrtf540

{\fonttbl\f0\fswiss\fcharset0 Helvetica;}

{\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;}

\margl1440\margr1440\vieww9000\viewh8400\viewkind0

    \pard\tx560\tx1120\tx1680\tx2240\tx2800\tx3360\tx3920\tx4480\tx5040\tx5600\tx6160\tx6720\ql\qnatural\pardirnatural


\f0\fs24 \cf0 name 1\

name 2\

name 3 \

name 4 \
```

The actual text that I wrote in the textfile was just this:

```
name 1
name 2
name 3
name 4
```

Why is this happening? Why wouldn't it just show the plain text? If I can't get it to do that, how can I get around this issue for when I run loops through the file.

Comment: "The file that I created is a textfile"... it's not a plain text file, it's an RTF file. If you want to create a plain text file, use Notepad not some fancy document processor.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is, in fact, not a programming problem but an issue creating a plain text file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are writing the file in RTF ("Rich Text") format, which is not plain text.  Those "weird unwanted characters" are being written there by your editor.  Use a plain text editor like Notepad to create your file, or explicitly save it as plain text.

Comment: it does the same thing when I save it as a .txt file and I am using text edit on my mac, not any fancy editor...what is the file extension I am supposed to be using?

Comment: okay I was able to save it as a .txt file using word but not using TextEdit. Works great now. Thanks!

Comment: I just opened the dodgey file with a simple text editor and it was perfect.
Thank you.
In my example it was a .yml file that VSCode was having trouble reading in UTF-8